# How can I add a limit to draggable area?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problems to add a draggable limit area to elements. I created a hook to manipulate draggable elements:

I need to add a limit to the draggable area so that the components do not leave their container.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useDraggable = (el) => {
  const [{ dx, dy }, setOffset] = useState({ dx: 0, dy: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
      const startX = event.pageX - dx;
      const startY = event.pageY - dy;

      const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        const newDx = event.pageX - startX;
        const newDy = event.pageY - startY;
        setOffset({ dx: newDx, dy: newDy });
      };

      document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

      document.addEventListener(
        "mouseup",
        () => {
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        },
        { once: true }
      );
    };

    el.current.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

    return () => {
      el.current.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    };
  }, [dx, dy]);

  useEffect(() => {
    el.current.style.transform = `translate3d(${dx}px, ${dy}px, 0)`;
  }, [dx, dy]);
};
export default useDraggable;
```

And, my component looks like:

```
const DragNote = ({ children }) => {
  const card = useRef(null);
  useDraggable(card);
  return (
    <div ref={card} className="item">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can have a condition and stop the `setOffset`:

```
const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    const newDx = event.pageX - startX;
    const newDy = event.pageY - startY;
    // your condition here 
    // if(newDx < 'something' && newDy < 'somethingelse')
        setOffset({ dx: newDx, dy: newDy });
};
```